# Make JSON with complicated string acceptable to the server

Tags: json, http-error

I attempted to upload the following JSON to the server:

```
{
    "sign": "cancer",
    "date": 30,
    "month": 10,
    "year": 2013,
    "reading": "vQdKU0SufpGmvkkyfvkdUr&yg/ rodatmifvkyfav ay:avjzpfrnf/ olwpfyg; rodapvkdaom udpörsm;udk rvkyfavaumif;avjzpfrnf/ vltrsm; olwpfyg;\ pdwf0ifpm;p&m jzpfaewufonf/ aiGaMu;udpö owdxm;NyD; udkifwG,fyg/ vuf0,faiGaysufaomaMumifh Mum;pdkufavsmf&udef; MuHKrnf/"
}
```

And the server returns HTTP 400.

Is there any modification I need to make to the JSON to make it acceptable to the server?

This is the code that performs the upload:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        String input = "{\"sign\": \"" + reading.getSign() + "\"" + ", \"date\": " 
                + reading.getDate() + ", \"month\": " + reading.getMonth() 
                + ", \"year\": " + reading.getYear()
                + ", \"reading\": \"" + reading.getReading() + "\"}";

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();                        

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
```

Comment: How are you uploading it? Please show your code.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the upload code.

Comment: Please tag your question with the language.

Comment: The problem wasn't about the language. It was the fact that the string didn't conform to the JSON standard. The same JSON in another language wouldn't work. As I'm working on the Android client, the language choice is obviously Java. I guess the iPhone developers will have a similar problem.

Thanks for trying to help, anyway. At least it made me feel that I wasn't alone. :)

Comment: I didn't say the problem was the language. You should tag your question with the language so that people will find it in their searches, and so that people answering the question will know what language to put the answer in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by encoding the string as a JSON string. One easy way to do that would be to use JSONObject from the json-simple API.

```
JSONObject inputJson = new JSONObject();
        inputJson.put("sign", reading.getSign());
        inputJson.put("date", reading.getDate());
        inputJson.put("month", reading.getMonth());
        inputJson.put("year", reading.getYear());
        inputJson.put("reading", reading.getReading());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not escaping special characters, generating json/sql/html/etc strings like that is problematic and should be avoided.

You should consider using a json library, there are built in ones in the WCF libraries or you could use a more lightweight one such as Json.NET http://james.newtonking.com/json to achieve this.

There are a few ways to do it in Json.NET but this one would be the simplest:

```
var temp = new { 
    sign    = reading.getSign(),
    date    = reading.getDate(),
    month   = reading.getMonth(),
    year    = reading.getYear(),
    reading = reading.getReading()
};
string jsonString = JObject.FromObject(temp).ToString();
```

Comment: Oops, i thought i had my filter set to c#. Ignore my choice of API - it's probably not suitable.

Comment: If only an API as simple existed for Objective-C and Java. Unfortunately, we are not developing our client for Windows 8, either. We'll keep note of your API so that if we happen to need it for some purposes, we wouldn't have to go asking on stackoverflow.